# How to run flask shell in PyCharm?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, command-line-interface

I created new flask project in PyCharm but I can't see how to run flask shell in integrated PyCharm python console window.

Name app is not defined when start console:
[image: Name app is not defined when start console]

I still can run command "flask shell" in integrated PyCharm terminal but it will start without code completion, hints, syntax checks, etc.

Flask app is defined in terminal:

[image: Flask app is defined in terminal]
Is there any way to start flask shell in integrated PyCharm python console?

Answer (score 13):

You can use a combination of [creating a request context for the Shell](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/shell/) (which `flask shell` does) and a [custom starting script for the PyCharm console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/console-python-console.html).

[image: Where to enter starting script in PyCharm preferences]

```
# Step 1: acquire a reference to your Flask App instance
import app
app_instance = app.create_app()
# I return app instance from a factory method here, but might be be `app.app` for basic Flask projects

# Step 2: push test request context so that you can do stuff that needs App, like SQLAlchemy
ctx = app_instance.test_request_context()
ctx.push()
```

Now you should have the benefits of `flask shell` alongside the code completion and other benefits that IPython Shell provides, all from the default PyCharm Python Shell.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (in my `server.py` I had `app=Flask(__name__)`)  I used

```
from server import app
ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()
```

Then added this to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Python Console` starting script

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```
from app import app
ctx = app.test_request_context()
ctx.push()
```

more on the [Flask docs page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/shell/)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59622870/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score -1):

[Running a Shell](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/#running-a-shell)

> To run an interactive Python shell you can use the shell command:
>
> ```
> flask shell
> ```
>
> This will start up an interactive Python shell, setup the correct
>   application context and setup the local variables in the shell. This
>   is done by invoking the Flask.make_shell_context() method of the
>   application. By default you have access to your app and g.

It's just a normal interactive Python shell with some local variables already setup for you, not an IDE editor with code completion, hints, syntax checks, etc.